# Why must my code include line = '' + '-' instead of line = '-'

Tags: python

CODE 1

```
name = 'World'
line = ''

for char in name:
    line = line + '-'
    
print(name)

print(line)
```

Versus

CODE 2

```
name = 'World'
line = ''

for char in name:
    line = '-'
    
print(name)

print(line)
```

Why doesn't code 2 have the output

```
World
-----
```

as well? I really don't get it

Comment: Could you please format it as code and one without syntax error, then someone could help you probably?

Comment: In the second code, what's your understanding of what `line = '-'` does?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `line = line + '-'` and `line = '-'`?

Comment: `=` is assignment operator, so what you end up is set `line` to `-`, then set it again to `-` and so on 5 times.

Comment: Well, because `line = '-'` does exactly what it says: line will always be '-', independantly of how many times this statement is executed!

Comment: BTW: Python can do `line = len(name) * '-'`.

Answer (score 3):

Just think about what this actually means:

```
for char in name: 
    line = '-'
```

The for keyword tells the interpreter to iterate over all characters in `name`. It will run `line = '-'` once for every character in `World`.

The first time `line = '-'` get's executed, the variable `line` gets set to `'-'`.
But so does it the second time. And the third time.

That's the difference between the two programs. In the first program you do `line = line + '-'`. You take the current `line` and add a further `'-'` at the end

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that line in loop is not aggragating the `-` char.

For doing so you have two options:

1. Like you did in your first code.

```
    for char in name:
        line = line + '-'
```

2. Like this.

```
    for char in name:
        line += '-'
```